# Calling static method in test class(Junit)

Tags: java, junit4

I am writing junit test cases for my project but i am facing one problem 
Here is a method that i am using in one of my java class (GraphNodes.java)

```
 public static ArrayList<String> getCSList() {
    System.out.println(CSList.size()); // Output : 3
    return CSList; // returns 3 elements in list
}
```

Now here is my test class for Junit

```
@Test
public void checkCSListCount(){

 int actual= GraphNodes.getCSList().size(); // My exceptation here is 3 but in console it shows 0
 int excepted = 3;
 assertEquals(excepted,actual);  
 }
```

My junit is failing by saying excepted<3> but actual<0>
Also i cannot change the static method to only public because it will affect some functionality of the code and since i am new to junit, i am not getting idea how to fix this.so can anyone help me out here
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: what's the content of that list? also ... you do understand that that is a very weird and pointless method to begin with?

Comment: the list of which the size you print in that method, is NOT the list you return, so why would it automatically be the same?

Comment: `deliveryLinkedAllCSList` is one thing, and `CSList` is another.  So, the fact that one seems to contain 3 elements says absolutely nothing about how many elements the other one contains.

Comment: @Mike Nakis  sorry it was a mistake i have edited the asked question,please have a look agian,Thank you

Comment: @Stultuske sorry it was a mistake i have edited the asked question,please have a look agian,Thank you

Comment: does that line print 3 when you execute your unit test?

Comment: @Stultuske when i execute my java class yes but when i run as junit then no

Comment: @RajatKrishnan then why would you expect your test to succeed? before executing the get, set values in that list. and use that length as expected value.

Comment: @Stultuske because when i am running my main class in console it shows 3 but when i run my test class as run as junit then its failing which should not be case as the size is 3 and my exceptation is 3

Comment: @RajatKrishnan your main method execution is not related to your unit test. As you just said: when you run your test, that line prints 0, so there is nothing in that list, hence, the expectation should not be 3 unless you actually put 3 elements in that list for the test, which you haven't.

Comment: @Stultuske so what according to you should be done here so that my junit test case could pass?

Comment: Option 1: add 3 elements to that list in your test, before the get. Option 2: change the expected value to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate how you populate the object `CSList()` during runtime and do exactly the same when you are running the test.

One option is to have a `@BeforeEach method` in your test where it will set the values of what you need during the test.

```
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
       GraphNodes.setCSList(Arrays.asList("A","B","C"));
    }


   @Test
   public void checkCSListCount(){

      int actual= GraphNodes.getCSList().size();
      int excepted = 3;
      assertEquals(excepted,actual);  
  }
```

Comment: this is going under the assumption that that List is expected for every test scenario. You may want to add the option of doing that setUp in the test method itself

Comment: Indeed @Stultuske. Something that the developer that asked should take in consideration. But you have a good remark. Voted up.

Comment: @Patrick Santana what i need is i don't want to set any value in test class rather than that i just want to call that function operation to be called in test class directly, also i have edited something in test class please have a look,Thank you!!

Comment: @RajatKrishnan I don't see the different. Something sets that value. If you don't call what sets, it will always be 0. I think we need more details to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to write an integration test. So you should call the method, that fills the list with your 3 elements, before checking the list size. If all the logic for that is in your main method you should extract it into its own method.